# I want Customization option as specific as mentioned in the link below - Please help

Tags: magento2, custom

https://www.romaniabathtubs.com/make-your-own-bathtub/serena.html

Can anyone help me build this customization option in **Magento**?

I don't know how would I add the custom checkbox that **updates live on selecting** and **changes the product image** simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a bundle product